# The "remove" button next to "Interesting Tags" shows up late and makes me click on it

Tags: feature-request

This drives me crazy!

I love the "Interesting Tags" feature of SO.  I use it almost exclusively and go there right when I hit the SO homepage.

The problem is, the way it renders now, the tags appear right away without the "Remove" buttons (little "X").  For a good 2-3 seconds they aren't there.  They jump in seemingly trying to catch me trying to click on a tag. There's not a confirmation on this remove - they just disappear.  This makes me utter a curse word I'd rather not repeat.

My problem isn't the lack of confirmation (yes!)... it's that the "X"'s are delayed (no!).

Does this drive anyone else crazy???  Am I the only one addicted to this feature?

This is my only complaint about SO.  Not bad, really.

Edit: I was thinking.  If you were able to just leave room for them, that would be perfect.  I don't care that they appear late.

Comment: Is this really a feature request?  I dunno... sorta borderline.  Seems sorta buggy to me.

Comment: Behaves as designed (done with javascript), you're asking for it to be improved.

Answer (score 1):

I generally just wait until they finish rendering.

Comment: Sure... not because you want to, but because you have to.  It's nitpicky really, but it would improve the usability of the site a lot for me.  This is my current "workaround", as well.  Also, you'll notice I didn't respond with "why didn't I think of that".  I think this is because I'm growing as a person.

Comment: @Anderson Imes - See I didn't point out that you really did say it either. :)